# Pure CSS Accordion - Hiding White space that the slide eases out into possible?

Tags: css, accordion

The problem is that the accordion has a 300px height which is being left as white space below the accordion itself when the slides are closed. This causes spacing issues, since anything below it has to come after this ease-out space.

After looking at my old CSS Accordion, it seems to be because the slide itself is set with a 300px height and in the old accordion it was only ~40px, then opened a ~200px slide after being clicked. (Though this jerked the screen around.) I'd like to avoid HTML5 if possible and only use javascript if there's no other choice.

Is there a quick/easy way to hide this space, or am I looking at finding another accordion again?

Here's a quick JSFiddle I made to show the problem http://jsfiddle.net/RahpC/4/

Old Accordion:

```
.vertical section{ width:100%; height:40px;
    -webkit-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
}
/*Set height of the slide*/
.vertical :target{ height:250px; width:97%; }
```

New Accordion:

```
#vertical{
    width:700px;
    height:300px;
}
```

The thing with the old accordion style is I think I'd have to change to using "#" to make the targets and I'm not sure how much I'd have to rewrite if that's the only solution.

The other solution is to remove the images I'm using in the slides and then reduce the overall size of the accordion, but that sort of defeats the point of what I'm doing.

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: You have another problem, which is if you add more slides you have to adjust the height of #vertical enourmously to make them fit.  Looking into it further..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is *NOT* imperitive that you use percentage values for the height's of the accordion elements, then this is a simple solution: http://jsfiddle.net/RahpC/18/

I changed...

```
#vertical{
    width:700px;
    height:auto; /* changed to auto from 300px */
}
#vertical li{
    height:50px; /* changed from 14% to 50px */
    width:100%;
    -moz-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
}
#vertical li:hover{
    height:200px; /* was 60% changed to 200px, can be made as high as you need */
    width:100%;
}
```

Nice thing here is you can add as many slides as you want and it will always work because height is defined specifically.

Comment: Oh that looks to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much! :D Hopefully that's it now haha, CSS really isn't my strong point.

Comment: @Jon If there are any other related problems post here as a comment and I will do my best to help.  When it comes to the current CSS standards, height is a particularly odd thing to play with and does not work well with percentage units.  Just modify the heights above as you need and all should work fine.  Nice bit of code btw, it works well.